# Eu sonhei ou as tags favoritas eram mostradas na ordem que eu selecionava?

Tags: suporte, tags

Percebi hoje que as tags que aparecem no quadro 'Tags Favoritas' da tela de questões haviam mudado de ordem. Aparentemente estão em ordem alfabética, mas eu tenho a forte impressão de que eu havia definido a ordem em que elas eram apresentadas anteriormente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora, ao editar, notei que não é permitido selecionar a ordem das tags, mesmo as novas adicionadas entram na posição correspondente do ordenamento alfabético crescente.

Alguém mais percebeu algo do tipo?

Isso foi realmente alterado ou eu viajei na maionese?

Answer (score 1):

Não me recordo de podermos ordenar, acho que nem seria necessário ordenamento, já que elas servem mais para realçar perguntas com as tags, seja aonde for que aparecerem.

Por exemplo tenho 3 tags, independe-te da ordem o que elas fazem no site é realçar:

> [image: realce de perguntas]

Veja que uma pergunta com [c#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) aparece com realce.

Existe também a página https://pt.stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged?tab=mytags

Ela exibe só as perguntas que contenham suas tags favoritas, no meu caso adicionei duas tags bem incomuns para teste: [html2canvas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html2canvas) e [jspdf](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jspdf), elas tem poucas perguntas, então deu para ter uma ideia, veja o resultado:

> [image: ordem]

A ordem parece ainda ser a cronológica

Comment: Ao clicar na tag nessa área ele filtra para exibir somente as perguntas que incluem a tag clicada. Seria o equivalentea digitar `[c#]` na barra de pesquisa de questões. Tem alguma forma de usá-las de modo composto também (o equivalente a `[c#][visual-studio]`, por exemplo ), mas eu não conseguir identificar qual é o truque para isso.

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza sim, mas independente disso o que estou afirmando é que ordenar as tags que serão usadas para filtragem ou para realce não teria utilidade, por isto que creio que seja improvavel que isto fosse possivel.

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza a ordenação é feita somente por 5 abas, a que poderia usar isto provavelmente é a aba https://pt.stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged?tab=mytags - no entanto independete da ordem das tags as perguntas não irão ficar ordenadas por tags

Comment: Sim as perguntas não eram ordenadas mesmo, essas ficam no cronológico. Foi só a impressão de que a memória muscular me levava a um local diferente ao filtrar por `[xamarin-forms]`, por exemplo, mesmo sem ter adicionado ou removido outras recentemente.

Comment: Só não vejo a funcionalidade do click na tag para filtrar como **inútil** (aliás uso mais para isso e desse jeito - individualmente). Acho bem mais rápido clicar ali do que ir no campo e digitar a tag entre colchetes, ou procurar na lista uma pergunta que contém uma das tags que eu quero para so então clicar nessa. Mas enfim, devo mesmo ter me enganado =). Obrigado

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza será que não foi algum sistema com drag'ndrop que você usou?

Comment: Não. passei a usar o Firefox recentemente, mas voltei no Chrome para ver e lá também não ordena. Vou parar com as dorgas -.-'.

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza eu achei que o FF esta tão bom, porque o deixou? Eu só não abandonei o Opera, porque ele tem uma meia duzia de coisas que nem o FF e nem o Chrome tem

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77598/discussion-between-diego-rafael-souza-and-guilherme-nascimento).

Comment: [Eu não estava locão](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368024/have-favorite-tags-always-been-alphabetized).